# Failed to create EJBContainer

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, integration-testing

I am trying to create EJBContainer in order to do some integration testing. here is the code:

```
Map properties = new HashMap();
properties.put(EJBContainer.MODULES, 
               new File[]{new File("target/classes"),  
               new File("target/test-classes")});
ec = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(properties);
ctx = ec.getContext();
```

It throws exception: `javax.ejb.EJBException: Can't find directory D:\jboss-4.2.3.GA\jboss-4.2.3.GA\common\lib`

Actually there is no common/lib directory in Jboss folder. When I debug the code inside of EJBContainer i see that the problem is in **JBossStandaloneEJBContainerProvider** class which seems the default container provider class. Is there a way to change this provider? Or maybe I am doing something incompatible?